# Cloud foundry p-mysql

Tags: cloud-foundry

**hello to all**

I have a problem when I try to bind laravel app to p-mysql service created, I get connection refused error and app deployment failed. 
what I tried to do/can do:

1. use cf-laravel-example instead of my application still not working
2. I can access service instance of p-mysql
3. I can ssh the container running mysql
4. delete service and create, bind it again to the app.

I am using cf-release 231, cf-mysql-release 26

when I ran 
**cf service-access**

I GET

Getting service access as admin...
broker: p-mysql
   service   plan    access   orgs
   p-mysql   100mb   all
   p-mysql   1gb     all

**My BINDING Service Instance INFO**

```
"VCAP_SERVICES": {
"p-mysql": [
{
"credentials": {
"hostname": "10.244.7.6",
"jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://10.244.7.6:3306/cf_13b087f4_9531_4550_bd20_9eb7952b0d22?user=WFUTfD2qic1hrXII\u0026password=5YBedtOkQuqB24GV",
"name": "cf_13b087f4_9531_4550_bd20_9eb7952b0d22",
"password": "5YBedtOkQuqB24GV",
"port": 3306,
"uri": "mysql://WFUTfD2qic1hrXII:5YBedtOkQuqB24GV@10.244.7.6:3306/cf_13b087f4_9531_4550_bd20_9eb7952b0d22?reconnect=true",
"username": "WFUTfD2qic1hrXII"
},
"label": "p-mysql",
"name": "lagask",
"plan": "100mb",
"provider": null,
"syslog_drain_url": null,
"tags": [
"mysql"
]
}
]
}
}
```

**The Error am getting**

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
[PDOException]

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Script php htdocs/artisan migrate --force handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
[RuntimeException]

Comment: Are there any network / security restrictions that could stop your app from connecting to port 3306 on 10.244.7.6?

Comment: I ran cf service-access and the output was:                                                           Getting service access as admin... broker: p-mysql service plan access orgs
p-mysql 100mb all
p-mysql 1gb all

Comment: or there is another way to look for access restrictions?